# How to download files?

Tags: python

Which module should be used for downloading?
I am trying to create downloader with python but can't do it. I am a beginner.

```
Link="http://file.download.url"
download(link)
```

Comment: And when you download, then what? Put it in a string? Save it to disk? Dump it to a HTTP response? (Also, note that Python is case-sensitive; `link` and `Link` are two different things.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use requests module

```
import requests 
r=requests.get(Link).content
```